# Reference to component before creation

Tags: qt, qml, referenceerror, qtquickcontrols2

I have a `TableView` object which consists of four `TableViewColumn` objects.

```
TableView {
        id: tableConfig
        model: tableModel
        anchors.fill: parent

        TableViewColumn{
            role: "name"
            title: "Channels"
            width: tableConfig.width/ tableConfig.columnCount

        }
        TableViewColumn{
            id: usageCol
            title: "Type"
            delegate: usageComboDel
            width: tableConfig.width/tableConfig.columnCount
        }
        TableViewColumn{
            title: "Device"
            delegate: deviceTypeComboDel
            width: tableConfig.width/tableConfig.columnCount
        }
        TableViewColumn{
            id: pinClmn
            title: "PIN"
            delegate: pinComboDel
            width: tableConfig.width/tableConfig.columnCount
        }
    }
```

Each ViewColumn is presented using its own delegate `Component` . In my application I want the model of `pinComboDel` (ComboBox) delegate to be changed depending on the user's choice in `usageComboDel` delegate. The two delegates are:

```
Component {
        id: usageComboDel
        Item{
            anchors.fill: parent
            ComboBox {
                id: usageCombo
                model:
                    ListModel{
                    id: usageModel
                    ListElement { text: "PowerOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "AnalogOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "PwmOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "DigitalOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "BldcOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "AnalogIn" }
                    ListElement { text: "PwmIn" }
                    ListElement { text: "DigitalIn" }
                    ListElement { text: "Can" }
                }
                currentIndex: 0
                height: 16
                anchors.fill: parent
                onCurrentTextChanged: {
                    tableModel.setProperty(styleData.row,"use",currentText);
                }
            }
        }

    }
Component{
        id: pinComboDel
        Item{
            id: itemPinComboDel
            anchors.fill: parent
            ComboBox {
                id: pinCombo
                model: {if (usageCombo.currentText === "PowerOut") { modelPowerOut;}
                    else if (usageCombo.currentText === "AnalogOut") { modelAnalogOut;}
                    else if (usageCombo.currentText === "AnalogIn") { modelAnalogIn;}
                    else if (usageCombo.currentText === "PwmOut") { modelPwmOut; }
                    else if (usageCombo.currentText === "DigitalOut" || usageCombo.currentText === "BldcOut" || usageCombo.currentText === "DigitalIn") { modelDigitalBldc; }
                    else if (usageCombo.currentText === "PwmIn") { modelPwmIn; }
                    else if (usageCombo.currentText === "Can") { modelCan; }
                }
                height: 16
                anchors.fill: parent
                onCurrentTextChanged: {
                    tableModel.setProperty(styleData.row,"pin",currentText);
                }
            }
            ListModel {
                id: modelPowerOut
                /* list elements */
            }
            ListModel {
                id: modelAnalogOut
                /* list elements */
            }
            ListModel {
                id: modelAnalogIn
                /* list elements */
            }
            ListModel {
                id: modelDigitalBldc
                /* list elements */
            }
            ListModel {
                id: modelPwmIn
                /* list elements */
            }
            ListModel {
                id: modelCan
                /* list elements */
            }

        }

    }
```

When I run the application I get
`ReferenceError: usageCombo is not defined` inside `pinCombo` ComboBox .

What I believe is causing this, is that, when I code the section `Component{ ...}` I am just declaring the existence of a component just as if I would have created it in a separate `.qml` file. **However**, this does not also mean that it is instantiated. The component is instantiated through `tableConfig` View when used as a ViewColumn's delegate. Therefore, the `pinComboDel` *cannot see* the `usageComboDel`'s index as for the first, the second does not exist.

I would name it something like 'Reference to component before it is created'.

One possible solution I have thought but not tried, is that I could create 6 separate delegates one for each model. However, for reasons of consistency and efficiency, I want to avoid this and develop things the right way.

So first, do I understand the problem correctly? Second, hence the two components are eventually instantiated as delegates, shouldn't they be able to *see* one another?Third, is this possible to happen? Or should I try to develop it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled the `delegate:` property directly into the `TableViewColumn` . I followed @folibis advice and created a property for the two columns and bonded them together. So when the first delegate is changed, the second gets updated.

```
TableViewColumn{
            id: usageCol
            title: "Type"
            property string modelName: "Power Out"
            delegate: ComboBox {
                id: usageCombo
                model:
                    ListModel{
                    id: usageModel
                    ListElement { text: "PowerOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "AnalogOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "PwmOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "DigitalOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "BldcOut" }
                    ListElement { text: "AnalogIn" }
                    ListElement { text: "PwmIn" }
                    ListElement { text: "DigitalIn" }
                    ListElement { text: "Can" }
                }
                currentIndex: 0
                height: 16
                anchors.fill: parent
                onCurrentTextChanged: {
                    tableModel.setProperty(styleData.row,"use",currentText);
                    usageCol.modelName = currentText;
                }
            }
            width: tableConfig.width/tableConfig.columnCount
        }
TableViewColumn{
            id: pinCol
            title: "PIN"
            property string modelName: usageCol.modelName
            delegate: ComboBox {
                id: pinCombo
                model: {if (pinCol.modelName === "PowerOut") { modelPowerOut;}
                    else if (pinCol.modelName === "AnalogOut") { modelAnalogOut;}
                    else if (pinCol.modelName === "AnalogIn") { modelAnalogIn;}
                    else if (pinCol.modelName === "PwmOut") { modelPwmOut; }
                    else if (pinCol.modelName === "DigitalOut" || pinCol.modelName === "BldcOut" || pinCol.modelName === "DigitalIn") { modelDigitalBldc; }
                    else if (pinCol.modelName === "PwmIn") { modelPwmIn; }
                    else if (pinCol.modelName === "Can") { modelCan; }
                }
                height: 16
                anchors.fill: parent
                onCurrentTextChanged: {
                    tableModel.setProperty(styleData.row,"pin",currentText);
                }
            }
            width: tableConfig.width/tableConfig.columnCount
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a delegate from outside due to scope issue. But a delegate can access its parent so it would be logical to create some external property and bind delegate to that. For example:

```
Row {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Repeater {
        id: main
        model: 5
        property color clr: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 50
            height: 50
            color: Qt.lighter(main.clr, 1.0 + index / 10)
            border { width: 1; color:"#999" }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                onClicked: {
                    main.clr = Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your advice was really helpful! Now the second's delegate model can be updated regarding the user's choice in the first. However, the model changes for all the table's cells. I want to change explicitely for each row and remain to this independently from the other rows. But I guess this is an extra issue to my question.

Comment: Sure, the example above is for illustration purposes only. You should apply your own logic.